# How to demonstrate: $(p→r)∧(q→r) ⇔ p∨q→r$

Tags: logic

How to demonstrate $(p→r)∧(q→r) ⇔ p∨q→r$ using the laws of logic?

Comment: Are truth-tables allowed? If not then what exactly are the laws of logic?

Answer (score 1):

p$\rightarrow$q= ($\neg$p)$\lor$q

Above expression is ([$\neg$p]$\lor$r)$\land$([$\neg$q]$\lor$r)

Which is ([$\neg$p]$\land$[$\neg$q])$\lor$r

Which is ($\neg$[p$\lor$q])$\lor$r

Which is  (p$\lor$q)$\rightarrow$r